# Wordpress custom loop showing duplicate content

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm setting up a custom loop in my custom_functions.php. The basic idea of the loop is this

```
 function category() {
   if (is_category(3557)) {
      News Category content
   }
   else{
      Main categories content
   }
 }
```

This works fine for all the main categories, but on the news page I'm showing the news content followed by the main site content.

Comment: Your code is out of context but if your 'news' category is 3557 then on 'news' category archive pages only the first part of that should run, not both. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was wrong - I'm working with the Thesis theme, and the example I found on how to start a custom loop had

```
else
  thesis_loop::category();
```

at the end. However, once I added actual content to override the default loop, I just needed to add brackets for the else statement, so it became

```
else {
   Main category content
}
```